# Is there a more efficient way to create a data.frame containing descriptions of each variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, metadata, mode

I have a data.frame in R (let's use the built-in dataset "mtcars" as an example) and I'd like to find a more efficient way to create a second data.frame containing descriptions of each variable (i.e. some basic metadata) in the following way:

```
Variables    Type                                   Labels
      mpg numeric                        Miles/(US) gallon
      cyl numeric                      Number of cylinders
     disp numeric                    Displacement (cu.in.)
       hp numeric                         Gross horsepower
     drat numeric                          Rear axle ratio
       wt numeric                        Weight (1000 lbs)
     qsec numeric                            1/4 mile time
       vs numeric      Engine (0 = V-shaped, 1 = straight)
       am numeric Transmission (0 = automatic, 1 = manual)
     gear numeric                  Number of forward gears
     carb numeric                    Number of carburetors
```

The code below indicates my current method for obtaining a data.frame with the descriptions of each variable including variable names, variable element types, and labels.

```
dat01 <- mtcars

Variables <- c(names(dat01))

#install.packages("Hmisc")
library(Hmisc)
var.labels = c(mpg="Miles/(US) gallon",
               cyl="Number of cylinders",
               disp="Displacement (cu.in.)",
               hp="Gross horsepower",
               drat="Rear axle ratio",
               wt="Weight (1000 lbs)",
               qsec="1/4 mile time",
               vs="Engine (0 = V-shaped, 1 = straight)",
               am="Transmission (0 = automatic, 1 = manual)",
               gear="Number of forward gears",
               carb="Number of carburetors")

label(dat01) <- as.list(var.labels[match(names(dat01), names(var.labels))])

Labels <- label(dat01)

Type <- c(mode(dat01$mpg),
          mode(dat01$cyl),
          mode(dat01$disp),
          mode(dat01$hp),
          mode(dat01$drat),
          mode(dat01$wt),
          mode(dat01$qsec),
          mode(dat01$vs),
          mode(dat01$am),
          mode(dat01$gear),
          mode(dat01$carb))

meta.df <- data.frame(Variables,
                      Type,
                      Labels)

print(meta.df, row.names = FALSE)
```

In addition to improving the efficiency of my script (specifically, I am confident that there is a more efficient code I can use to create the vector "Type"), I am also interested to hear your suggestions on how best to generalize this script so that it can be copy/pasted and applied to similarly structured data.frames.

Comment: `Type = sapply(mtcars, mode)` would be pretty standard. The way to make it generalizable is to put it into a function, probably a function of the data, taking custom labels as an optional argument.

Comment: I'd also question whether you're sure `mode` is the information you want. `class` is a lot more useful, but then you do have to decide what to do with multiclass objects. But things like `mode(factor(1:3))`, `mode(Sys.Date())`, `mode(Sys.time())` are all `numeric`, which makes me dislike mode.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that mode is numeric. When I use mode(variable.name), it returns a character string indicating the type of data element (i.e. "character", "numeric", "logical", etc.). It seems that class(variable.name) does the same thing, except that sapply(dat01, class) also returns a row indicating that each column in my data frame is "labeled".

Comment: Yes, `mode` and `class` return character strings. `mode(Sys.Date())` returns the character string `"numeric"`, because dates are stored internally as numbers. `class(Sys.Date())` returns the character string `"Date"`. My point is that the information that `class` returns is more useful, as factors, dates, and timestamps and integers will all be identified by `mode` as simply `"numeric"`, but `class` will distinguish between them and regular numerics. The information returned by `class` is usually more helpful.

Comment: `test_list = list(date = Sys.Date(), time = Sys.time(), factor = factor('a'), integer = 1L, numeric = 1.5)`. Compare `lapply(test_list, mode)` to `lapply(test_list, class)`. But here you can also see that `class` doesn't necessarily return strings of length 1, `class(Sys.time())`, `class(factor('a', ordered = T))` are two base examples with multiple classes... which can make things harder. Picking `class(x)[1]` would be a pretty good default.

Answer (score 0):

A first fix would be to deduplicate that `Type` definition:

Since `class(some_vector)` returns a single string describing the data-type in that vector, and since a data-frame is a list of vectors you can use code like this:

```
Type <- unlist(Map(class, mtcars))
```

[you might need to reorder the entries though]

Comment: `class` does not consistently return a single string. Try `class(factor(1:3, ordered = TRUE))` or `class(Sys.time())` for examples of multiclass objects that frequently show up as data columns.

Comment: apologies, my mistake